# indicator only works when gaps are disabled ( when indicator is set on a specific timeframe) and when on cloud doesn't work

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have made this indicator on trading view that fills the distance between to moving averages (and it's called a cloud) when I set the indicators timeframe ( for example on weekly) the cloud doesn't  work on other timeframes like daily ( when gaps are on) and it only works when gaps are off but that makes all the lines disconnected . Do you know what I can do to make it work to not have disconnected lines( gaps on ) and with a working cloud?

```
StudyName        = "MA Cloud"
ShortStudyName   = "MA cloud" 
study(StudyName, shorttitle=ShortStudyName, overlay=true, resolution="", resolution_gaps = 
false)

source = input(close, title="Source")
typeofMA1 = input(title="Type of Moving Average", defval="EMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", 
"WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "TMA", "HullMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "VWAP"])
length_ma1 = input(30, title = "[ALL but VWAP] Length of Moving Average 1", 
type=input.integer)
typeofMA2 = input(title="Type of Moving Average", defval="EMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", 
"WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "TMA", "HullMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "VWAP"])
length_ma2 = input(74, title = "[ALL but VWAP] Length of Moving Average 2", 
type=input.integer)

color_candles = input(true, title="Color based on trend?")

f_smma(src, len) =>
    smma = 0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

f_hullma(src, length) =>
    wma(2 * wma(src, length / 2) - wma(src, length), round(sqrt(length)))

f_tma(src, length) =>
    sma(sma(src, length), length)

f_dema(src, length) =>
    emaValue = ema(src, length)
    2 * emaValue - ema(emaValue, length)

f_tema(src, length) =>
    ema1 = ema(src, length)
    ema2 = ema(ema1, length)
    ema3 = ema(ema2, length)
(3 * ema1) - (3 * ema2) + ema3 

f_ma(smoothing, src, length) =>

     iff(smoothing == "RMA",    rma(src, length), 
     iff(smoothing == "SMA",    sma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "EMA",    ema(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "WMA",    wma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "VWMA",   vwma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "SMMA",   f_smma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "HullMA", f_hullma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "VWAP",   vwap(hlc3),
     iff(smoothing == "DEMA",   f_dema(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "TEMA",   f_tema(src, length), src))))))))))

MA1 = f_ma(typeofMA1, source, length_ma1)
MA2 = f_ma(typeofMA2, source, length_ma2)

plot_ma1 = plot(MA1, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=3, title = "MA1")
plot_ma2 = plot(MA2, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=3, title = "MA2")

fill_color = MA1 > MA2 ? color.new(color.green, 60) : color.new(color.red, 60)
fill(plot_ma1, plot_ma2, color=fill_color)

 // Candles coloring
 clr = not color_candles ? na : 
 MA1 > MA2 ? color.new(color.lime, 40) : color.new(color.fuchsia, 40)

barcolor(clr,title="Trend State Bar Colouring")

cond_buy  = MA1 > MA2 and crossover(MA1, MA2)
cond_sell = MA1 < MA2 and crossunder(MA1, MA2)

// green triangle
plotshape(cond_buy, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, 
color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.large)
// red triangle
plotshape(cond_sell, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, 
color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.large)


alertcondition(cond_buy,  title='Buy Alert', message="Buy Alert")
alertcondition(cond_sell,  title='Sell Alert', message="Sell Alert")
```